# Why does the margin affect whether my inline-block divs will align to the top using flex-start?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm just learning css and html and I'd like to understand things better.

When displaying 3 divs in an inline block I wanted to align them all to the top of the flexbox section. It seemed like "align-items: flex-start;" was the code that should do that, but the divs did not react. I was trying different things and it worked once I added "margin:1vmax;" to the div attributes. Why did it not work without that? What's the underlying principle here?

```
        section{
            background:cadetblue;
            padding: 20px 20px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: flex-start;
        }

        div{
            background:black;
            color: white;
            height:auto;
            width: 25%;
            padding: 0.5em 2em;
            margin:1vmax;
            text-align: justify;
            text-justify:inter-word;


        }
```

Comment: ...but I suspect what you wanted was `align-content` not `align-items`

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-content/

Comment: @Indraneelan nope, your code's working without margin, the problem was with  other elements: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/zQgbaq

Answer (score 0):

```
        Hey there is nothing wrong in the code you didn't added any content in the div's so that's why you are not able to see the difference.

          <section>
            <div></div>
                <div> Your reducer function's returned value is assigned to the accumulator, whose value is remembered across each iteration throughout the array and ultimately becomes the final, single resulting value.</div>
            <div> sfsdfsfs s sf sf s s saf sa saf</div>

          </section>

     section{
                background:cadetblue;
                padding: 20px 20px;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                align-items: flex-start;
            }

            div{
                background:black;
                color: white;
                height:auto;
                width: 25%;
                padding: 0.5em 2em;
                margin:1vmax;
                text-align: justify;
                text-justify:inter-word;
            } 

check here:https://jsbin.com/yevipowusi/edit?html,css,js,output
```